# Points and algebraic geometry on the quantum plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, qa.quantum-algebra, associative-algebras

The "quantum plane" is the "space" of the algebra $A=\Bbbk\langle X,Y\rangle/(YX-qXY)$, for a scalar $q$ (e.g. $\Bbbk=\mathbb C(q)$). I would like to know how much algebraic geometry has been done on it, and would love references.

Let us say a polynomial $f\in A$ *left-vanishes* at $(x,y)\in\Bbbk^2$ if it belongs to the left ideal $A(X-x)+A(Y-y)$. I want to think of this ideal as the "left point" $(x,y)$; this is not the same thing as the right ideal $(X-x)A+(Y-y)A$.

(1) Say the *variety* of a left ideal $I$ is the set of left points at which all $f\in I$ left-vanish; and the ideal of a variety is the intersection of its points. It seems that, as one would expect, the variety of the ideal of $V$ is $V$, and the ideal of the variety of $I$ is the radical of $I$.

(1') Of course the same statements hold with right ideals and right-vanishing.

(2) More vicious: say a polynomial $f\in A$ *left-right-vanishes* at $(x,y)$ if $f\in A(X-x)+(Y-y)A$. This codimension-$1$ subspace of $A$ deserves to be called a "left-right point". Does one still have the goodies $V(I(V))=V$ and $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$, where by "left-right ideal" I now mean a subspace on which $X$ acts on the right and $Y$ acts on the left, namely a $\Bbbk[Y]$-$\Bbbk[X]$-bimodule?

Comment: The book [K. A. Brown and K. R. Goodearl, Lectures on algebraic quantum groups. Basel: Birkhäuser (2002; Zbl 1027.17010)] contains lots of detailed exposition of the study of the quantum plane and other related noncommutative algebras, from the point of view of noncommutative geometry (specifically their (H-)prime ideals, where H refers to the natural torus action).

Comment: Thanks @JanGrabowski! However, it seems to me that that book (and the literature it led me to) only considers two-sided ideals.

Comment: Well, yes. That's why I didn't put it as an answer, since it doesn't directly address your question. But among my colleagues, primes and H-primes would generally be regarded as the (noncommutative) algebraic geometry of this and related algebras. I'm not aware of literature looking at 1-sided ideals, but thought there might be references to chase in Brown-Goodearl, if any do exist. You could also try reverse search, i.e. look on MathSciNet or Zentrallblatt for more recent citations of B-G.